# WatchSimulator 3.1 SDK does not support x86_64 architecture?

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, ios-simulator, cpu-architecture, watchos-2

This is the warning message appears when I compile my WatchKit 2 app

> ignoring file
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator3.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//WatchKit.framework/WatchKit,
>   file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked
>   (x86_64):
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator3.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//WatchKit.framework/WatchKitld:
>   warning: ignoring file
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator3.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//Foundation.framework/Foundation,
>   file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked
>   (x86_64):
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator3.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//Foundation.framework/Foundation

And, finally, it failed to compile

> ld: entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture x86_64

Architecture allowance in build setting is : i386 and x86_64.

However, if I force architecture to x86_64 only (which I dont want to apply for my project forever). There is another error

> ld: illegal text-relocation to 'non_lazy_ptr' in

And I added `OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -read_only_relocs suppress` as recommended from some answers in stackoverflow.
But Xcode kept the same error message.

*Edited: oh, my another mistake. This should be `OTHER_LDFLAGS =`... something.*

Could any one give me any ideal how to overcome this.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.

Because I mistakenly set my WatchKit extension's architecture for WatchSimulator be `i386 x86_64`. Xcode automatically selected x86_64.

However, Watch Simulator SDK does not support x86_64. Because all current watch OS is built only for 32-bit architecture.

After I removed `x86_64` from the architecture setting, Xcode builds my target with i386 architecture.

Then the warning and error disappeared.

Many thanks,

Comment: That is correct. All Apple Watch devices are 32-bit.